# nat-io's graft library needs all raft node communicate with central nats server(developed by nats-io)

Tags: nats.io, raft

the code I referenced currently was below.

```
func createNatsNodes(t *testing.T, name string, numNodes int) []*Node {
opts := &nats.DefaultOptions
url := fmt.Sprintf("nats://%s:%d/",
    test.DefaultTestOptions.Host,
    test.DefaultTestOptions.Port)
opts.Url = url

ci := ClusterInfo{Name: name, Size: numNodes}
nodes := make([]*Node, numNodes)
for i := 0; i < numNodes; i++ {
    hand, _, logPath := genNodeArgs(t)
    rpc, err := NewNatsRpc(opts)
    if err != nil {
        t.Fatalf("NatsRPC error: %v", err)
    }
    node, err := New(ci, hand, rpc, logPath)
    if err != nil {
        t.Fatalf("Expected no error, got: %v", err)
    }
    nodes[i] = node
}
return nodes
```

}

we can see each node must connected a server's url. It increase another component in the architecture.
I was told before each raft node should be rpc client and server in the meantime rather than a central server in this library.
I want to know if it is possible to use the `github.com/nat-io/graft` library to construct this kind of raft node.